# NVIDIA CUDA 4.0, page-locking a memory with runtime API

Tags: gpu, nvidia, cuda

NVIDIA CUDA 4.0 (RC2 is assumed here) offers the nice feature of page-locking a memory range that was allocated before via the "normal" malloc function. This can be done using the driver API function:

```
CUresult cuMemHostRegister (void * p, size_t bytesize, unsigned int Flags);
```

Now, the development of the project was done so far using the runtime API. Unfortunately it seems that the runtime API does not offer a function like cuMemHostRegister. I really would like to avoid mixing driver and runtime API calls.

Does anyone know how to page-lock memory that was prior allocated using standard malloc ? Standard libc functions should not be used, since the page-locking is carried out for staging the memory for a fast transfer to the GPU, so I really want to stick to the "CUDA"-way.

Frank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 4.0 runtime API offers `cudaHostRegister()`, which does exactly what you are asking about. Be aware that the memory allocation you lock must be host page aligned, so you probably should use either `mmap()` or `posix_memalign()` (or one of its relatives) to allocate the memory. Passing `cudaHostRegister()` an allocation of arbitrary size from standard `malloc()` will probably fail with an invalid argument error.